# Docker : oci runtime error: exec: "/bin/bash": stat /bin in windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I am using windows 7. In my home folder I made a new directory Docker. And inside that I made new directory rails.

This is my docker file: (Docker/rails/Dockerfile)

```
FROM alpine:3.2
MAINTAINER xxx <xxx@xxx.in>

ENV BUILD_PACKAGES bash curl-dev ruby-dev build-base
ENV RUBY_PACKAGES ruby ruby-io-console ruby-bundler

# Update and install all of the required packages.
# At the end, remove the apk cache
RUN apk update && \
    apk upgrade && \
    apk add $BUILD_PACKAGES && \
    apk add $RUBY_PACKAGES && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN mkdir /usr/app
WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY Gemfile /usr/app/
COPY Gemfile.lock /usr/app/
RUN bundle install

COPY . /usr/app
```

And then I changed directory to Docker. On ls it shows rails.
Then I typed this command:

```
docker build rails
```

Now the image name is alpine. I made a tag to rails like this:

```
docker tag <imageid> myname/rails
```

**Problem:**
The image is successfully build and I have a repository rails and pushed it successfully. I am able to pull it as well.
Till now everything is fine, but then I run this command:

```
docker run -i -t xxx/rails /bin/bash
```

It gives me this error:

```
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: exec: "/bin/bash": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory.
```

So I am stuck there.

**My Objective**:
I want to run this command successfully:

```
rails -v
```

To run that command I need to install the image, and I don't know how to install the image, I have been following up numerous tutorials since last week.
I am new to docker. This is my first docker image.

Edit:
docker exec -it  sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alpine does not come with bash by default, only `/bin/sh` so you should change your command to:

```
docker run -i -t vikaran/rails sh
```

Also worth noting you can run:

```
docker build -t myname/rails rails
```

To automatically tag the image when building it.